# PHP Url Rewrite mod-rewrite

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

(Referring to http://www.webconfs.com/url-rewriting-tool.php -- using url http://mywebsite.com/urltest/product.php?categoryid=1&productid=10)

1. Enabled Apache Module -- Rewite_Module
2. I have created a page product.php
   Write the code so that - it shows the content - when i request the page as:
    http://mywebsite.com/urltest/product.php?categoryid=1&productid=10
3. Then I created .htaccess in my project root (that is, in /urltest/)
   and added the following code to it:

   Options +FollowSymLinks
   RewriteEngine on
   RewriteRule product/categoryid/(.*)/productid/(.*)/ product.php?categoryid=$1&productid=$2
   RewriteRule product/categoryid/(.*)/productid/(.*) product.php?categoryid=$1&productid=$2

But, when I take: http://mywebsite.com/urltest/product/categoryid/1/productid/10/
I get the error:
Not Found

The requested URL /urltest/product/categoryid/1/productid/10/ was not found on this server.

(As I mentioned direct url, works fine - http://mywebsite.com/urltest/product.php?categoryid=1&productid=10)

Pl help

Comment: `/productid/(.)/` match `/productid/1/` but not `/productid/10/`: `.` = one character (except `\n`)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have a rewrite base problem.
Have your code like this

```
Options +FollowSymLinks -MultiViews

RewriteEngine on 
RewriteBase /urltest/

RewriteRule ^product/categoryid/([^/]+)/productid/([^/]+)/?$ product.php?categoryid=$1&productid=$2 [L]
```

Comment: I have applied it to .htaccess. Still not working                        By the way the url i tried is mywebsite.com/urltest/product/categoryid/1/productid/10  as well as mywebsite.com/urltest/categoryid/1/productid/10

Comment: Sorry i forgot to disable `MultiViews` option in my answer. You can try again with my edited code, should be working as expected now

Comment: Did you allow htaccess files in your Apache config ? Also, do you have other rules in your htaccess ? Or other htaccess files in root folder or subdirectory ?

Comment: u mean rewrite is enabled? if so yes.   There is no other .htaccess files in root or within the web folder

Comment: No it's not about rewrite since you said in your question it was enabled. I meant htaccess files may not be executed. Try to put some garbage (random characters) in your htaccess and tell me if you have an error

Comment: I put some garbage in htaccess & now the error changed - Internal Server Error

Comment: This means your htaccess file is well executed. Do you have other rules (or code) in your htaccess except the one in my answer ?

Comment: Hey.. it worked now... The only change is in between the trials, I restarted Apache. Thank you